# fetching primary key of inserted row with details view

Tags: asp.net, detailsview

i use a details view to insert sum data in my sql server database
it's table has a Primary Key named ID and this pk is identity enabled so it generated automatically!
after inserting i need to fetch inserted row's pk and i use this code

```
protected void DetailsView1_ItemInserted(object sender, DetailsViewInsertedEventArgs e)
{

    int id = Convert.ToInt32(e.Values["ID"]);
    Response.Redirect("BakhshnameAppendix.aspx?ID=" + id.ToString());
}
```

but it always returns 0 !
how can i get inserted ID ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
protected void DetailsView1_ItemInserted(object sender, DetailsViewInsertedEventArgs e)
{

   int intKey;
   if (int.TryParse(e.ReturnValue, out intKey))
   {
         Response.Redirect("BakhshnameAppendix.aspx?ID=" + intKey.ToString());
   }
}
```

Comment: i use Details view and it's automatic Inserting,and i don't use any sql query for insert

Comment: @user1461377 please re check. The answer is edited. hope it helps you.

Comment: i got this error ' CS1061: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewInsertedEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'ReturnValue' and no extension method 'ReturnValue' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewInsertedEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

' e hasn't ReturnValue property

Comment: use the ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs instead of DetailsViewInsertedEventArgs

Comment: i got this error message : Error 3 No overload for 'DetailsView1_ItemInserted' matches delegate 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewInsertedEventHandler'